# Picture element usage when image sizes known

Tags: image, responsive-design

I want my responsive Webpage to load the appropriately sized images. I currently have an HTML template that looks like:

```
  <picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 950px)" srcset="{{ .Cover.Large }}">
  <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="{{ .Cover.Medium }}">
  <source media="(min-width: 300px)" srcset="{{ .Cover.Small }}">
  <source media="(min-width: 150px)" srcset="{{ .Cover.Xsmall }}">
<img src="{{ .Cover.Medium }}" alt="{{ .Title }} poster">
  </picture>
```

Large = 950x400
Medium = 600x252
Small = 300x126
Xmall = 150x63

Now I'm thinking this min-width is not going to work very well if the pictures are in a row or flexed. Isn't it best to define the dimensions of the image and let the browser download the most suitable source?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#valid-source-size-list

What's the cleanest way to do this? Confusingly in my own responsive experiments, the Large size is always loaded:

[image: Large image always loaded]

- [Picture element](https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/gr9odmjj/1/embedded/result/)
- [Img srcset](https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/je07phjt/2/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted, 4 images flexed across a screen that are backed with multiple renditions of the JPG in order to save client bandwidth. Note the code is missing a src= attribute to make it valid.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
picture {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<picture>
<img
srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=XSmall&w=150&h=63 150w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Small&w=300&h=126 300w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Medium&w=600&h=252 600w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Large&w=950&h=400 950w" sizes="calc(25vw - 2em)">
</picture>
<picture>
<img
srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=XSmall&w=150&h=63 150w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Small&w=300&h=126 300w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Medium&w=600&h=252 600w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Large&w=950&h=400 950w" sizes="calc(25vw - 2em)">
</picture>
<picture>
<img
srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=XSmall&w=150&h=63 150w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Small&w=300&h=126 300w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Medium&w=600&h=252 600w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Large&w=950&h=400 950w" sizes="calc(25vw - 2em)">
</picture>
<picture>
<img
srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=XSmall&w=150&h=63 150w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Small&w=300&h=126 300w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Medium&w=600&h=252 600w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=89&txt=Large&w=950&h=400 950w" sizes="calc(25vw - 2em)">
</picture>
```

So I learnt several things:

- [How to flex images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761602/how-to-make-image-flex-to-its-width)
- **picture.img** is fine, you don't need to use the [source element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element)
- learnt about **vw** the view port size width, which is like a percentage of the screen, but you must you absolute values when calculating margins, e.g. `calc(25vw - 2em)`. 25vw = 1/4 of screen with the picture margins 1em+1em either side
- this stuff is really complicated, this example doesn't even [use break points](https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/), which I would suggest you avoid for your sanity!

It does exactly what I want it to do. It loads the appropriately sized and bandwidth efficient image. If resizing down, it doesn't load a smaller image, which I want. And when it scales up, it  does fetch a larger higher resolution image, which I do want in order to avoid any ugly artefacts.

**Result**: Efficient transfer of several JPG renditions

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using the same image for each scenario but only in different sizes? If so, you can probably just use the `srcset` attribute rather than the `<picture>` element.

The `<picture>` element is used when you require art direction-based selection, like if you're using a wide shot for the large screen and a portrait crop on a narrow screen, for example. The thing about the `<picture>` element is that it's used in situations where we want a specific image to display at a specific breakpoint, hence there is no ambiguity in terms of image selection when using the `<picture>` element.

Which links back to my original question, are you using the same image for each screen width but simply in different sizes? If so, a normal img element with the `srcset` attribute would serve you much better.

For fluid-width images, `srcset` will be used with the `w` descriptor and `sizes` attribute. There are two values in the `sizes` attribute. The first is a media condition. The second is the source-size-value, which determines the width of the image given that particular media condition. Below is an example of the `srcset` syntax:

```
<img srcset="uswnt-480.jpg 480w, 
             uswnt-640.jpg 640w, 
             uswnt-960.jpg 960w,
             uswnt-1280.jpg 1280w" 
     sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 
            (max-width: 960px) 75vw, 
            640px" 
     src="uswnt-640.jpg" alt="USWNT World Cup victory">
```

Here, I’m telling the browser that for viewport widths up to 400 pixels, make the image 100% of the viewport width. At viewport widths up to 960 pixels, make the image 75% of the viewport width. And for everything above 960 pixels, make the image 640 pixels. The browser utilises the information from `srcset` and `sizes` to serve the image that best matches the stated conditions.

*Full disclosure: I lifted a lot of this from an article I wrote previously on this topic*