# How to make image flex to it's width?

Tags: css, flexbox

how do I prevent my image from being stretched over it's natural 200px width?

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
}
img {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <img src=http://www.placebacon.net/200/150>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try removing flex property of the img tag.

Comment: Not the answer, but just a note that it's best practice to enclose all HTML attributes in quotes. And technically to close the tag with a slash. So, <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/200/150" />

Comment: what do u mean? set img to 100%; ?

Comment: How do you need the picture to be displayed? In the original width of image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the flex off of the image and set max-width to 100%. This will allow the image to grow to it's max size and shrink if it's parent shrinks. Then add align-items: flex-start to the container. This will allow the aspect ratio to remain intact if it shrinks.

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
img {
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <img src=http://www.placebacon.net/200/150>
</footer>
```

Comment: Is "align-items: flex-start;" needed?

Comment: It is needed to keep the aspect ratio of the image intact when the footer shrinks between the natural width of the image. If that won't occur then it's not necessary.

Comment: why isn't flex: 1 needed?

Answer (score 1):

You could toss it into a simple container, and use that for flexing:

```
<footer>
  <div>
    <img src=http://www.placebacon.net/200/150>
  </div>
</footer>
```

```
footer {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1em;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the need for the extra div. I prefer Brian's answer.